# integerity error in django(i think its about that new foregn key)

Tags: python, django, web

im have post model and a profile model on profile model i have a `OneToOneField` this is my profile model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



class Profile(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = [('boy', 'پسر'), ('girl', 'دختر'), ('i prefer not to say', 'ترجیح میدهم نگویم')]


    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pictures', blank=True, default='default.jpg')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    age = models.IntegerField(default="0")
    birth_day = models.CharField(max_length=30)#DateField(blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, default="---")
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=300, blank=True, default="---")
    phone = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    skills = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True, default="ترجیح میدهم نگویم")
    favorites = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True, default="ترجیح میدهم نگویم")
    favorite_books = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True, default="ترجیح میدهم نگویم")
    favorite_movies = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True, default="ترجیح میدهم نگویم")
    favorite_musics = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True, default="ترجیح میدهم نگویم")
    favorite_sports = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True, default="ترجیح میدهم نگویم")
```

and this is my post model:

```
from django.db import models
# from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
from user.models import Profile


class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = [('published', 'published'), ('draft', 'draft')]

    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to="posts_images", null=True)
    image_alt = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True, null=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='published')
    author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = TaggableManager()

    published_manager = PublishedManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meat:
        ordering = ('-publish_date',)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post:post_details', args=[self.slug,])
```

and i can change the previuos posts and save them but i can't add a new post get this error

```
IntegrityError at /admin/post/post/add/

NOT NULL constraint failed: post_post.owner_id
```

you can see that owner_id before i add the profile model i connect djangouser with a foregnkey with post model and its variable was 'owner' but now i deleted but i still get it's error and also when i migrated the new profile i get somethings like error but they was'nt error they was some things like warnings or something like that thanks for helping

Comment: show your form please

Comment: Have you changed your `Post` model and not run migrations? You have no `owner_id` field there!